# Getting json data from second tier / nest down

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I need to do a PHP if statement on one object in a json array in a .js page.

The output of the page at https://haspdenbloodglucose.herokuapp.com/api/v1/status.js gives me `"units":"mmol"`and I need to check if this is `mmol` or `mgdl` from another page then convert the units if needed. I was thinking about my if statement needs to be `sgv = 100`

```
if ($units == "mmol") {
    $sgv = $sgv/18; // converts the units to mmol/l from mg/dl
    $sgv = round($sgv, 1); // round to 1 decimal place
} else {

}
```

I'm fairly confident in, however getting the value of "units" or specifically setting the value of `$units` from that json array is another story.

It looks to be in the second nest down (if thats the right word) however I've never seen text before the opening `{` before.

so I would start with a file get contents as :

```
$status = file_get_contents('https://haspdenbloodglucose.herokuapp.com/api/v1/status.js' );
```

but can I do a

```
$json = json_decode($status);
```

when I try

```
echo $json;
```

to test this has decoded it comes back blank ?

however

```
echo $status;
```

comes back ok so I know that parts is working. What am I missing ?

Comment: If `$json` is blank it means `$status` is not valid JSON. Looking at the output I see it looks like a javascript assignment. If you strip the `this.serverSettings = ` off the beginning and the `;` off the end if should decode ok.

Comment: If I call the given url in a browser the first few chars print out `this.serverSettings = `. So your response, which you get with `file_get_contents` is no valid json data. So your return value of `json_decode` is NULL. For more detailed error messages just use `json_last_error_msg()`.

Comment: did you really mean `$sgb` as in NOT `$sgv` ?

Comment: yes updated now, thanks